# Collapse all list and expand only the selected list in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-list-group with 2 sub-group inside it like in the image shown below. Whenever I click the parent list-group other groups are getting collapsed, but when I click a sub-group inside a list-group, other sub-group inside the list-group are not getting collapsed. Ex: when I click Admin, the Actions sub-group is not getting collapsed.

codepen: https://codepen.io/eajithkumar128/pen/BaoEeqW?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Flists%2F

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
      class="mx-auto"
      width="300"
    >
      <v-list>


        <v-list-group
          prepend-icon="account_circle"
          value="false"
        >
          <template v-slot:activator>
            <v-list-item-title>Users</v-list-item-title>
          </template>

          <v-list-group
            no-action
            sub-group
            value="true"
          >
            <template v-slot:activator>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>Admin</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </template>

            <v-list-item
              v-for="(admin, i) in admins"
              :key="i"
              link
            >
              <v-list-item-title v-text="admin[0]"></v-list-item-title>
              <v-list-item-icon>
                <v-icon v-text="admin[1]"></v-icon>
              </v-list-item-icon>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list-group>

          <v-list-group
            sub-group
            no-action
          >
            <template v-slot:activator>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>Actions</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </template>
            <v-list-item
              v-for="(crud, i) in cruds"
              :key="i"
              @click=""
            >
              <v-list-item-title v-text="crud[0]"></v-list-item-title>
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon v-text="crud[1]"></v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list-group>
        </v-list-group>
       <v-list-group
          prepend-icon="account_circle"
          value="false"
        >
          <template v-slot:activator>
            <v-list-item-title>Users</v-list-item-title>
          </template>
        </v-list-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this can be simply done by using a v-model with every v-list-group. Something like this:

```
<v-list-group v-model="SubActive[header+subheader]" no-action sub-group v-for="(subheader, sIndex) in header.SubHeaderList" :key="sIndex" >
    <template v-slot:activator>
        <v-list-item-content v-on:click="subToggle(header,subheader)">
            <v-list-item-title>
                <span>{{subheader.Title}}</span>
            </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
    </template>
```

SubActive is a Vue data object with keys as header+subheader (to uniquely identify each subheader) and its initial value will be set to false for all subheaders.

The subToggle function will simply switch the rest of the values to false(to collapse them all except the one which is clicked):

```
subToggle(brand, category) {
             
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.SubActive).length; i++) {
        if (brand + category != Object.keys(this.SubActive)[i]) {
            this.SubActive[Object.keys(this.SubActive)[i]] = false;
        }  
    }
},
```